# How to kernel test a custom formatter for an entity reference field type?

Tags: 8, testing

We have a custom field formatter for a string and an entity reference field type. While this works for testing the string field:

```
   $node = $this->createNode(['type' => 'page', 'field_id' => 'foo12345']);
   $build = $entity->field_id->view('default');
   $this->assertSame('Custom Label', $build['#title']);
   $this->assertSame('foo12345', $build[0]['#context']['value']);
```

The same does not work for an entity reference field type. `$build` is always empty:

```
    $node1 = $this->createNode(['type' => 'page', 'field_id' => 'foo12345']);
    $node2 = $this->createNode(['type' => 'page', 'field_ref_field' => ['target_id' => $node1->id()]]);
    $build = $node2->field_ref_field->view(['type' => 'my_plugin']);
    $this->assertSame('Custom Label', $build[0]['#title']);
```

I tried checking some of the core tests around reference field displays but came up short. Why does ->view() not return a build array (other than the cache metadata) for an entity reference field?

**edit**: it seems that in the test, this part of the formatter plugin returns nothing from 'getEntitiesToView' (but works on the actual site):

```
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) : array {
    $elements = [];

    foreach ($this->getEntitiesToView($items, $langcode) as $delta => $entity) {
      $id = $entity->field_id->value;
      $uri = $entity->toUrl();
      $label = $this->formatLabel($id) . ' ' . $this->stripCharacters($id);

      $elements[$delta] = [
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title'=> $label,
        '#url'  => $uri,
        '#options' => $uri->getOptions(),
      ];

      $elements[$delta]['#options'] += ['attributes' => []];
      $elements[$delta]['#cache']['tags'] = $entity->getCacheTags();
    }

    return $elements;
```